# How to highlight epub text in android

Tags: android, epub

From reading some Q&As on stackoverflow, I understand that webview might be a good option to display epub files.

In the following thread, it mentioned you can highlight in webview too.
[render the epub book in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518257/render-the-epub-book-in-android)

Can anybody guide me as to how we can highlight some text in web view?
There's a similar question asked about 2 months ago in the following thread but has not received an answer yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948352/highlight-unhighlight-some-text-permanently-in-epub-file-in-android

Please help me to figure out how I can implement highlight functionality for epub readers in android.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to be able to permanently save changes to the epub files? I don't think it's possible as `WebView` is read-only... you might be able to use JavaScript though and keep track of changes with that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't think WebView would be able to save changes. But basically, what I would like to do is like iBook reader on iPad. I would like to highlight or add comments to epub. Should I just use label instead to show epub texts?

Comment: I don't think it will be too easy; you would have to make your own epub renderer/viewer. For example this is a [PDF renderer](http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/); I'm not sure how epub renderers work. Or, again, you could try using the JavaScript interface in `WebView` in order to make changes to the document (and perhaps somehow save those changes as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         webview.findAll(htmlTextStr);
         webview.setSelected(true);
         webview.findNext(true);
```

Try this , htmlTextStr must be your text that is to be highlighted

Answer (score 1):

```
I am giving this answer based on my experience into development of native epub player for android and ios.
I had achieved it in this way .

This is the way I have done text highlighting

- once your url loads into webview in onload call back inject jquery lib to webview dom like this


    private void addJQueryJS() 
        {
            String path = "file:///android_asset/JSLibraries/jquery.min.js";
            String data = "{\"MethodName\":\"onJQueryJSLoaded\",\"MethodArguments\":{}}";
            String callBackToNative  = " jsInterface.callNativeMethod('jstoobjc:"+data+"');";
            String script = "function includeJSFile()"
                                   +"{"
                                   +"function loadScript(url, callback)"
                                   +"{"
                                   +"var script = document.createElement('script');"
                                   +"script.type = 'text/javascript';"
                                   +"script.onload = function () {"
                                   +"callback();"
                                   +"};"
                                   +"script.src = url;"
                                   +"if(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0])"
                                   +"{"
                                   +"(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);"
                                   +"}"
                                   +"else { callback(); }"
                                   +"}"
                                   +"loadScript('"+path+"', function ()"
                                   +"{"
                                   +callBackToNative
                                   +"});"
                                   +"} ; includeJSFile();";
            loadUrl("javascript: "+script);
        }

wrap each word into a span with a unique id

then create a js file and inject same as jquery and write touch methods in it 


    function onTouchMove(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        if((touchendStartStick == true || touchendEndStick == true) && currHVO != undefined)
        {
            var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
            var obj = document.elementFromPoint(touch.pageX-window.pageXOffset,touch.pageY-window.pageYOffset);

            if($(obj).is('span'))
            {
                $(obj).css('background-color','rgba(0,0,255,0.3)');
            }
        }
    };


you can get word x,y width height values also .so you can show start ,end draggable pins on native view.

you can save highlight by saving the first and last word id of an highlight into db or to some persistent storage.Next time when user opens the book get those words ids and highlight those spans .
```